# jQuery click hander slow to run after many clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, event-handling, click

I'm trying to bind a click handler to several elements on the DOM. Once clicked, the element loads some new content in a shadowbox. After playing with the code for a little while, I noticed it took progressively longer to load each time I clicked.

I tested this by disabling all the click handler's function except a simple console.log. Even after this, by the 15th click, the response got slower and slower. It didn't matter which post I clicked, or even if the content had already been loaded-- it really starts to slow down around the 15th click on this '.shadowbox-link' element.

Here is my click handler:

```
$j('#content article .shadowbox-link').bind('click', showShadowboxPost);
```

Which goes to the function:

```
    var showShadowboxPost = function() {

    // Unbind click handler
    $j(this).unbind('click', showShadowboxPost);

    // Variables for ajax request
    var postData = {
        'postId':     $j(this).attr('data-id'),
        'postType':   $j(this).attr('data-type'),
        'elementId':  $j(this).attr('id'),
        'prevPost':   $j(this).prev().attr('id'),
        'nextPost':   $j(this).next().attr('id')
    };

    preFadeIn();

    // If content already loaded, avoid ajax request
    // The following functions include the fadeIn
    if($j(this).children('.single-post').length !== 0) {
        preLoadedRequest(this)
    } else {
        ajaxRequest(postData, this)
    }

    // Rebind click handler
    $j(this).bind('click', showShadowboxPost);

    return false;
};
```

Full file here: http://www.clarkthomasny.com/wp-content/themes/cleanslate/js/shadowbox-post.js

The HTML is basically like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="articles">
      <article class="shadowbox-link"></article>
      <article class="shadowbox-link"></article>
      <article class="shadowbox-link"></article>

      [etc..]

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the page its at: http://www.clarkthomasny.com/

I tried to debug this several different ways but I'm still not sure what's going on and think it must have something to do with binding the click handler to so many elements? I've been working with jQuery a few years now and I'm stumped, please help. Thanks!

Comment: why are you unbinding and binding the same handle to the element inside the handler

Comment: It wouldn't cause the progressive slow-down you mention, but since you're asking about performance you shouldn't keep calling `$j(this)` throughout your function - cache it in a variable instead.

Comment: Hasn't on() replaced bind()?  Would using the newer method have a performance impact?

Comment: Thanks @Seano666 I didn't realize on() and replaced bind(). I replaced this, since I should anyway, but it didn't seem to affect anything. The page still gets really slow and stops responding to clicks at a certain point.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I unbound and bound inside the handler so no click events could fire by accident before I could perform the function I intended. Then at the end of the function I rebind it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the native DOM handler

```
document.getElementById('anchorID').onclick=function(){/* some code */}
```

Comment: Why? Why would the OP's code get progressively slower in a way that your suggestion would fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! The error was unrelated to the code I posted. Another file contained a click hander for all links (it's a bad idea, I know) and I was accidentally binding it twice. Thus the accumulated slowness. Thanks everyone for your help!